# Move files by folders

Tags: batch-file, cmd, move

I have

> D:\folder\1.jpg,
>   D:\folder\2.jpg,
>   D:\folder\3.jpg
>   .... so on

I need

> D:\folder\1\1.jpg,
>   D:\folder\2\1.jpg,
>   D:\folder\3\1.jpg
>   ....

This code

```
 FOR /R %I IN (*.jpg) DO (md %~nI; move %I %~dI%~pI%~nI\1.jpg)
```

create folders like `D:\folder\1\1.jpg\`

What I do wrong?

Comment: Do this. Produces errors, but it works.  `FOR /R %I IN (*.jpg) DO (md %~nI & move %I %~dpI%~nI\1.jpg)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command creates folders like `D:\folder\1\1.jpg\` because `;` is a parameter delimiter and cannot be used for daisy-chaining commands. For the latter you have to use `&`.

There are several other issues with your command, too.

- You create the destination folder in the current working directory (`md %I`) but then move the file using the full path (`%~dI%~pI%~nI\1.jpg`). This will fail as soon as there are subfolders with .jpg files in the current working directory.
- You don't quote the variables, so the command will also fail when a path or file name contains spaces.
- Moving the files to subfolders creates an endless loop with the recursive folder traversal (`for /r`).

I'd suggest to run two separate loops, one for creating the destination folders and the second for moving the files:

```
for /r %I in (*.jpg) do @mkdir "%~dpnI"
for /r %I in (*.jpg) do @move "%~fI" "%~dpnI\1%~xI"
```

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
FOR %I IN (*.jpg) DO (
  MD %~nI & copy %I %~nI\1.jpg & del %I)
```

use `&` for pipe the continuous command. also in [`move`](http://ss64.com/nt/move.html) you can not rename so i just use `copy`